# What types of enemies can't take cover?

Tags: xcom-2

After playing through quite a few missions, I've come across a number of different enemies that seem to be unable to take cover (which I've found by mind-controlling/hacking them).

For example, in the screenshot below, I'm mind-controlling a Berserker, and when I move the cursor next to high and low cover, no cover icons appear.

[image]

**Which types of enemies do not make use of cover?**

Answer (score 8):

So far, I've found that the following types of enemies are unable to use cover (presumably because they're too big, or because they float/fly around all over the place):

1. Mecs
2. Archons
3. Sectopods
4. Berserkers

The following types of enemies also cannot use cover (as pointed out and confirmed by [Chris Hayes in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255220/what-types-of-enemies-cant-take-cover/255221#comment354497_255221):

5. Gatekeepers
6. Faceless
7. Chryssalids
8. Andromedons (after they revive)
9. Psi Zombies

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. In addition, Andremedons can't take cover after they revive, and Psi Zombies can't take cover at all.

Comment: @ChrisHayes you can mind control a Psi Zombie? That's so funny!

Comment: I don't know if you can mind control them - I'd actually assume not. I just know that an AI-controlled one won't take cover, even if it ends its turn in a cover square.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can mind-control them, but you can mind-control something (like a Gatekeeper) and make your own. :)